# Not able to generate log when migrate from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x using bridge jar in spring boot web application

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from log4j1.x to log4j2.x.

```
Followed this link - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html
```

But I am not seeing logs are generated after changing it. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Here is the detail -
Exisging log4j version -

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

This is replaced with -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
 <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I can see **log4j-1.2.17**.jar is replaced with these four jars-

1. log4j-jcl-2.6.2.jar
2. log4j-core-2.1.jar
3. log4j-api-2.1.jar
4. log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar

This is the existing configuration file (filename **/usr/local/log4j.properties**) -

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/var/log/access.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Replaced this system property value -

```
logging.config=/usr/local/log4j.properties
```

with these two lines

```
log4j1.compatibility=true
log4j.configuration=/usr/local/log4j.properties
```

Comment: The `logging.config` property suggests you use Spring Boot. Spring Boot configures logging programmatically, therefore the `log4j.configuration` property will probably not work. However most recent versions of Spring Boot support Log4j 2.x natively. BTW: the version of Log4j 2.x you are using has several serious security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes, I am using spring boots. Any suggestion on how to set log4j.configuration?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: We are using spring boot 1.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot **reconfigures** your logging framework at a very early stage. That's why your external `log4j.properties` file is replaced by Spring during your application startup.

If you don't provide a `logging.config` property, a fixed list of classpath resources will be used (cf. [list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration)) or a default configuration is applied.

On a **recent** Log4j version you just need to set the system properties:

```
logging.config=/usr/local/log4j.properties
log4j.configurationFactory=org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationFactory
```

However you can not use a recent version because:

1. a breaking change (cf. [LOG4J2-1547](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1547)) in `log4j-core` renders version 2.7.0 and later incompatible with Spring Boot 1.2.x,
2. a [series of security vulnerabilities](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) restricts your choice even further to version 2.3.2.

Using version 2.3.2 you need to convert your `log4j.properties` file into the Log4j 2.x format (you can use the converter [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41824206/11748454)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration name="Log4j1">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="/var/log/access.log"
    filePattern="/var/log/access.log.%i">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5MB" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and set the system property:

```
logging.config=/path/to/the/file/above.xml
```

**Remark:** Spring Boot provides a series of starters, which pull the correct dependencies. In order to use Log4j 2.x you just need to exclude the standard `spring-boot-starter-logging` and include `spring-boot-starter-log4j2`. No explicit Log4j dependencies are needed (except `log4j-1.2-api` if you use Log4j 1.x in your code):

```xml
  <properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.3.2</log4j2.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: You are right that logging.config=/usr/local/log4j.properties needs to be used instead of log4j.configuration=/usr/local/log4j.properties. This worked. What tried is defined in the official document and unfortunately did not work.

Comment: `log4j.configuration` **does** work for a couple of seconds between the application start and the logging reconfiguration performed by Spring. Add `log4j2.debug=true` to your system properties if you want to check how many times the logging system is reconfigured.

Comment: I did the same configuration for migrating log4j-1-x to log4j-2-x. But all the logs are generated on the console after starting spring boot application and I am using Log4j 1.x in my code. Log files are generated as defined in log4j2.xml but all files are empty.